# QWebView: Stretch to fill screen size?

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I'm new to QT mobile development and am trying to work out how to stretch a QWebView to fill the entire user screen. I found the showFullScreen() method but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Can anybody advise if this is possible?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

You need to put QWebView object in the layout. For any kind of UI implementation using qt it is important to understand layout management.
Following links can help you in that:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html

Comment: I put the QWebView widget onto my layout using the QT Creator ui designer. The widget works as expected, except I can't can it to automatically fill the screen.

Comment: Add QWebView object in you parent widget, then select parent widget and choose one of layouts (horizontal, vertical, or grid). Also for QWebView set size policy to expending.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is the supplement of mrmcduff, please try the below method:

```
void setSizePolicy (QSizePolicy::Policy horizontal, QSizePolicy::Policy vertical)
```

set both of the parameters to be `QSizepolicy::Expanding`, write a demo to test and view it, it should be very useful to Qt layout, at least I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the layout you've got the QWebView in has 0 margin.  You may want to verify that you're not accidentally adding padding or margin inside QWebView.  You also want to set your [size policy](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) to stretch.

Which version of Qt are you using?